# Does the two-fingered secondary click not work in Windows8.1/Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, trackpad, windows

I just setup a Windows 8.1 installation on my 2012 MacBook Air using Bootcamp (5.1.5640). I've noticed that the two-fingered secondary click doesn't appear to work even when configured via the Bootcamp Control Panel - however two-fingered secondary tap seems to do it. I've verified that the trackpad doesn't seem to have any hardware issues - the two-fingered click works just find in OSX.

Is this a known issue or have I set this up incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar trackpad issues using Windows on my 2012 Macbook Air and fixed it using 3rd party software called [Trackpad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com). Give it a try.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Although it is not a strait answer to the OP, it is a valuable answer to the problem at hand.

Comment: But if you uninstall Trackpad++, your trackpad stops working because removing the application doesn't remove the driver.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue with the MacBook Air. I can also report similar problems. [Trackpad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/), for me, solved my issues. You may want to try it, as it is free.

Comment: Do you have any reference as to this being a known issue with the Macbook Air? i.e. anything from Apple? Does this work with other Macs? Or other versions of Mac OSX?